# Why does std::num::Wrapping not implement BitAnd<u64> and other non-wrapped integer types?

Tags: rust

[`Wrapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.Wrapping.html) implements the following for the `&=` operator:

- `BitAndAssign<[u/i]xx>`
- `BitAndAssign<&[u/i]xx>`
- `BitAndAssign<Wrapping<[u/i]xx>>`
- `BitAndAssign<&Wrapping<[u/i]xx>>`

However, it only implements the following for `&`:

- `BitAnd<Wrapping<[u/i]xx>>`
- `BitAnd<&Wrapping<[u/i]xx>>`

Why are `BitAnd<[u/i]xx>` and `BitAnd<&[u/i]xx>` not implemented?

Comment: What do you expect the result of `3u32 & Wrapping(1u32)` to be? Will it be the a `u32` or a `Wrapping<u32>`? For `BitAndAssign`, there is no ambiguity, but for `BitAnd` there is.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, for an asymmetric operation like this, I think it should adopt the left-side type. This type of ambiguity is everywhere in programming languages and we resolve them through convention, like operator precedence and associativity. So `Wrapping<u32> & u32` is `Wrapping<u32>`.

Comment: This kind of ambiguity is the reason rust does not support, e.g., `1u32 + 1u16`, which C resolves by "conventions" that have caused a lot of surprises to programmers. _Sometimes_ it's necessary to resolve ambiguities, but Rust has generally refused the temptation to guess where not absolutely necessary.

Comment: The "sometimes" is very gray for me. It seems I'm reading about exceptions and special behavior in Rust all the time. Hey look, [`>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Shr.html)  is an example where they've chosen to adopt the left-hand type in a two-operand operator.

Comment: For the `&` operator, there should be no difference between `a & b` and `b & a`, so mixing types and picking the left-hand type would be arbitrary. Right shift is not a convincing argument since it doesn't have that property.

Comment: The right-hand side of a right-shift counts the number of bits. It's always a primitive integer type. For right shifts, there is no ambiguity about the resulting type.